# Relative layout positionnement

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

i'm new in Android developement(sorry for my english i m french).
I have an application with a listview.
For the listview i have a custom line.

I want to have this result :

[image]

Here is my code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="60dp"
    android:gravity="end" >

    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/messageID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/messageContactID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"/>

    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/messageContact"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/previewContact"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    />

    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/messageText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/messageContact"
    android:background="@color/home_bg"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Could you please help me?

Ps i cant use linear layout

Comment: In your image i see only messageText and messageContact, what about the two others TextView's? how you want to place them?

Comment: Can you elaborate more that what you exactly want to do?

Comment: The two others text view arent displayed. they are here for the cursor apadter (the cursor adapter require _id)

Comment: I want to reproduce the image but i dont know how to do that.
I want that the message take the entire width of the screen on the left of th contact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="60dp"
    android:gravity="end" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageContactID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageContact"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/previewContact"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@color/home_bg"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/messageContact" />
</RelativeLayout>
```